# Raising a maximumly optimized tarrasque

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters, optimization, necromancy

What would be the most powerful undead type to raise a tarrasque as and would regeneration work with undead counting charisma for their health instead? I'm looking for the maximum beefy killing machine.

Comment: Hi Syx660, welcome to the site. I see you've taken the [tour], you can also check out [this meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9185/48759) for other places to get help. Or ask me in the comments with @linksassin. This question has quite a bit going on and I'm not sure exactly what you are asking. We have a one question per post policy so it would help oif you focus on the actual issue you are having. Give us the full details of your character and what you are trying to achieve is a good place to start. Good luck!

Comment: It may be best to simplify this question to something really basic like *I just killed the tarrasque. What are the requirements to animate it as a zombie, and what kind of stats does it have when I do?* Then let other, separate, new questions develop from there.

Comment: It probably would be better but theres just so much I cant even find at this point that I have alot of questions.

Comment: Why don't you start by explaining what inspired the question. What happened at the gaming table that made you ask this?

Comment: Well it's more just I've had a huge want to play a necromancer. With the setup I have I have the potential to be a super powerful necromancer and eventually lich. And I'm striving to be the final big bad after we take out the current living liches. As well I already know of a tarrasque that is living in this campaign.

Comment: Okay. Cool. Now, of the several questions in this question—like *What changes occur to the tarrasque when it's animated with animate dead?* and *What variant undead creatures can a dead tarrasque be animated as?* and *What features does an undead tarrasque retain when it's animated with animate dead?* or something else—, what's the most important question? Then edit the question to ask *just that one* most important question. Folks tend to give more than what's asked, so maybe answers to just that one question will answer the others. If they don't, then just ask another new question.

Comment: Well I feel that the variant question can easily be taken out. But the hd question and what would remain I feel I should keep. Thank you!

Comment: What undead template are you raising it with? Different templates cause different abilities to stay and different changes based on HD.

Comment: I read something wrong somewhere I dont know how but it's clear I shouldn't of. But the HD thing is nul and void. Though now it's more a question of what to raise it as that would make it the strongest